# how to place logo with negative z-index above navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I tried to place my logo (which I made in CSS) above the navigation bar. The logo has a negative z-index. I tried to fix it. But I still don't know how to fix it. When I load the code it places the logo over the navigation bar. Can anybody help me to place the logo above the navigation balk?

HTML:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="random.css">
   </head>

   <body>
   <div class="logo">
   <h1 class="neon" data-text="[Home page]">[Home page]</h1>
   </div>

   <div class="menubalk">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>


   </body>



    </html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300');

body {

  background: url(bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

}



.neon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 6em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #ff005b;


}

.neon:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #ff005b;
  filter: blur(15px)
}

.neon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fe3a80;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: .5;
  filter: blur(40px);


}

ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;

}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #262626;
  position: relative;

}

ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #00bcd4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

ul li:hover a:before {
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

Comment: Try to force it and use `!important` !!

Comment: I just started learning html and css. So I don't know how to apply it in my code.

Comment: `z-index: -1 ! important;` do you want it under or on your nav bar ?

Comment: do you want it under or on your nav bar ?

Comment: I want to place my logo above my nav bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `position:absolute` on .neon takes it out of the flow of the DOM and will put it above (over the top of) other elements. You can achieve the centering you need without it.

To solve your problem I did the following:

- Changed .neon display to 'inline-block'
- Changed .neon position to 'relative'
- Changed .neon:after content to '' (empty)
- Removed z-index from .neon:after
- Changed z-index of .neon:before to -1

Click 'Run code snippet' below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300');

body {

  background: url(bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;

}



.neon {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 6em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #ff005b;
}

.neon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;  
  color: #ffffff;
  filter: blur(15px)
}

.neon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fe3a80;
  opacity: .5;
  filter: blur(40px);


}

ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  background: white;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;

}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #262626;
  position: relative;

}

ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #00bcd4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

ul li:hover a:before {
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
   <body>
   <div class="logo">
   <h1 class="neon">Logo</h1>
   </div>

   <div class="menubalk">
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>


   </body>
```

Comment: In the snippet it seems like the problem isn't solved

Comment: Did you not want the logo to be above the navigation pane?

Comment: But in the snippet the logo is placed over the navigation pane

Comment: Right, I think I know what you mean now. There was some confusion between what you meant by over and what you meant by above. They sound like the same thing to me. I've updated my snippet. Try checking it now.

Comment: Updated explanation as well.

Comment: Thank you it works! Sorry for my unclear explanation.

Comment: No problem, we got there in the end!